# How to get collection of uploaded files from IOwinRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, owin

I am able to access form fields from `IOwinRequest` using `ReadFormAsync()` method.

But how can I access collection of uploaded files? Is there an API for that?

(I am looking for an alternative to ASP.NET's `HttpRequest.Files` property.)

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I have extracted the solution from Nancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not directly supported, you need a multipart mime parser. WebAPI has one, and I think Nancy also has one.